# How to fix Eclipse Maven Package Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets, war

I am trying to build a simple Servlet, that should only return me the content that was sent with the request. It does not build though I did not do anything different then before qhen I made another Servlet a year ago (that does not compile anymore either).

I do not understand the Problem as I haven't made anything different then before. Has anyone an Idea what it might be?

I suspect it might have something to do with the maven-war-plugin as it sais in the errors something about an maven-war-plugin:2.2, which seam odd to me as I am not using that version. Does someone know how I could enforce the use of the current version I put in the pom.xml, to see if that would solve it?

It sais:

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project LoginTest: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties

After this Error I get:

```
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:57)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.PropertiesConverter.<clinit>(PropertiesConverter.java:46)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.setupConverters(XStream.java:647)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:445)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:385)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.<init>(XStream.java:342)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.util.WebappStructureSerializer.<clinit>(WebappStructureSerializer.java:47)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.AbstractWarMojo.<init>(AbstractWarMojo.java:316)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(WarMojo.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$ReflectiveProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:114)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:98)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:112)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:127)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:66)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:306)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1050)
    ... 39 more
```

My pom.xml looks like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>eu.jlmb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ServletTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>ServletTest Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
  
    <dependencies>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20211205</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>ServletTest</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Why do you have maven plugins as dependencies? Does not make sense. Remove them. Defining plugins via pluginManagement

Comment: It did work, thank you. And it makes sence. The only thing I do not understand now, is why this worked before.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a simple version of the servlet you want to add?  Looking at the code can be very frustrating if there's no code at alll.  Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to know why this is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by khmarbaise, my problem was that I had the plugins listed as dependencies in the pom file. Adding them correctly as plugins and removing their information from the dependecies fixed it for me.

My pom depnedencies and build now look like this:

```
<dependencies>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.9.0</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin -->
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>-->
    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>LoginTest</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```